# Can a out of memory error be caused by a database's size?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web application written in `PHP` with a `MySQL` db. It is a streamlined and performing framework. It's online for over 5 years, every day users sign up and/or contribute to grow a single database, always bigger.

What has been happening for about 15 days is that 1 or 2 times a day the error occurs

> `PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated X (tried to allocated Y bytes)`

I have a shared hosting service, `memory_limit` is set to 512 MB
The database downloaded via backup (`.sql`) is about 750MB, but in the disk the space exceeds 1GB.

Can the database size affect? Or is it because there are so many requests that generate critical conditions to the server?

Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: Depends on how much data you're pulling from the DB at once - e.g. if you're assigning all the records from a table to a variable, then the more data there is in the table, the more memory that variable will require.

Comment: Make sure you're only getting the data you need. A large table can generate that error if you're get all of the records in that table.

Comment: That error is not (directly) to do with the size of your *database*. It is saying that *while running your PHP*, you have created variables which take up more than 512MB between them. For instance, `while(true) { $a[] = 'hello'; }` could theoretically create so many copies of `hello` in memory that you'd get that error, without any database at all. As such, this question is unanswerable with the information given.

Comment: That error message should provide a line number. Is there any specific reason that you felt the need to omit the line number and chose to not provide the code which is at that line number.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus To be fair, for out of memory errors, it's a matter of luck whether the line number shows you anything useful. If you allocate 511.999 MB in one function, and then try to allocate a few bytes somewhere else, the error won't tell you anything about where the 511.999 MB went.

Comment: I have worked constantly 5 years, paying attention to the improvement of MySQL queries. At the beginning, when the database was small, I did not have to face performance problems. Then, query after query, analysis after analysis, I understood many things, and applying them: therefore, always reduced volumes of extracted data, different cron services that regularly generate some cache files, in order to avoid very challenging and frequent queries. However, there is one type of query I think I have to check better and realize if that type of query could be the problem.

Comment: Apparently in my pc there are no problems to run the application with memory_limit = 128 MB, I could also make attempts with smaller limits. So, I would like to know if memory_limit consider the single request or is it cumulative and therefore many connected users contribute to the achievement of 512 MB? Honestly, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of slowdowns, in which errors such as occurred frequently

- PHP Fatal error: Out of memory
- Mysql too many connections
- Can not connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

I contacted the technical support and they told me that there is a DDoS attack